# Nginx Alias vs Rewrite

Tags: comparative-review, url, nginx

I have two working configurations that, on the surface, seem to do the same thing. They both accomplish the functionality that I need:

```
location ~ ^/(css|images|js)/ {
    location ~ '^/(css|js)/[0-9]{8}-(.*)$' {
        alias /$1/$2;
    }
    root /server/path/to/web/root;
}
```

**AND**

```
location ~ ^/(css|images|js)/ {
    rewrite '^/(css|js)/[0-9]{8}-(.*)$' /$1/$2 break;
    root /server/path/to/web/root;
}
```

They both take a URL like `/css/87654321-styles.css` and deliver the file `/css/styles.css`. I lean toward the second solution because it's more succinct, but I don't know if one is better than the other for performance reasons, unintended side-effects, etc.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27406188/244826) my original SO post, for reference/context.

After being directed to the [documentation for the Nginx rewrite module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html), I found these interesting lines:

> The ngx_http_rewrite_module module directives are processed in the following order:
>
> - the directives of this module specified on the server level are executed sequentially;
> - repeatedly:
>
>   - a location is searched based on a request URI;
>   - the directives of this module specified inside the found location are executed sequentially;
>   - the loop is repeated if a request URI was rewritten, but not more than 10 times.

So, if I used the `rewrite` directive without the `break` flag, there could be at least one additional loop of the `server` level directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `alias` is like `root`, so you need to use full server path
2. you can add `break` flag to `rewrite` for avoid internal redirect. *added* without break rewrite will make loop (internal redirect) for process all locations again; but `break` tell to rewrite do not loop and run current location.

I don't think here big difference in performance. Main difference is changing internal request uri. But in case of static files serve both work well.

Comment: If I use the `break` flag, will it still apply the following `root` directive in the current location? Will it process any subsequent `location` directives?

Comment: Yes, break will stop rewrite module directives only. Not 100% shure about nested location, but 99% :) Easy to check.